# Can't get Jest to work with Styled Components which contain theming

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

## The Problem

I've been using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) and [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) to write tests for my React components build with the awesome [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/) library.

However, since I've implemented theming all my tests are breaking. Let me give you an example.

This is the code of my `LooksBrowser` component (I've removed all of my imports and prop-types to make it a little more readable):

```
const LooksBrowserWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 56.25%;
`;

const CurrentSlideWrapper = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
`;

const NextSlideWrapper = CurrentSlideWrapper.extend`
  z-index: 1;
`;

const SlideImage = styled.img`
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
`;

const SlideText = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: ${PXToVW(72)};
  height: 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const SlideTitle = styled.p`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  color: ${props => props.color};
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily};
  font-size: ${PXToVW(52)};
`;

const SlideSubtitle = SlideTitle.extend`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideSubtitle.FontFamily};
`;

export default class LooksBrowser extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentSlide: {
      imageURL: this.props.currentSlide.imageURL,
      index: this.props.currentSlide.index,
      subtitle: this.props.currentSlide.subtitle,
      textColor: this.props.currentSlide.textColor,
      title: this.props.currentSlide.title
    },
    nextSlide: {
      imageURL: this.props.nextSlide.imageURL,
      index: this.props.nextSlide.index,
      subtitle: this.props.nextSlide.subtitle,
      textColor: this.props.nextSlide.textColor,
      title: this.props.nextSlide.title
    },
    nextSlideIsLoaded: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setVariables();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // Only update the state when the nextSlide data is different than the current nextSlide data
    // and when the LooksBrowser component isn't animating
    if (this.props.nextSlide.imageURL !== nextProps.nextSlide.imageURL && !this.isAnimating) {
      this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {
        nextSlide: {
          imageURL: { $set: nextProps.nextSlide.imageURL },
          index: { $set: nextProps.nextSlide.index },
          subtitle: { $set: nextProps.nextSlide.subtitle },
          textColor: { $set: nextProps.nextSlide.textColor },
          title: { $set: nextProps.nextSlide.title }
        }
      }));
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.isAnimating) {
      if (this.state.nextSlide.imageURL !== '' && this.state.nextSlideIsLoaded) {
        // Only do the animation when the nextSlide is done loading and it defined inside of the state
        this.animateToNextSlide();
      } else if (this.state.currentSlide.imageURL !== this.props.nextSlide.imageURL && this.state.nextSlide.imageURL !== this.props.nextSlide.imageURL) {
        // This usecase is for when the LooksBrowser already received another look while still being in an animation
        // After the animation is done it checks if the new nextSlide data is different than the current currentSlide data
        // And also checks if the current nextSlide state data is different than the new nextSlide data
        // If so, it updates the nextSlide part of the state so that in the next render animateToNextSlide will be called
        this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {
          nextSlide: {
            imageURL: { $set: this.props.nextSlide.imageURL },
            index: { $set: this.props.nextSlide.index },
            subtitle: { $set: this.props.nextSlide.subtitle },
            textColor: { $set: this.props.nextSlide.textColor },
            title: { $set: this.props.nextSlide.title }
          }
        }));
      } else if (!this.state.nextSlideIsLoaded) {
        // Reset currentSlide position to prevent 'flash'
        TweenMax.set(this.currentSlide, {
          x: '0%'
        });
      }
    }
  }

  setVariables() {
    this.TL = new TimelineMax();
    this.isAnimating = false;
  }

  nextSlideIsLoaded = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {
      nextSlideIsLoaded: { $set: true }
    }));
  };

  animateToNextSlide() {
    const AnimateForward = this.state.currentSlide.index < this.state.nextSlide.index;
    this.isAnimating = true;

    this.TL.clear();
    this.TL
      .set(this.currentSlide, {
        x: '0%'
      })
      .set(this.nextSlide, {
        x: AnimateForward ? '100%' : '-100%'
      })
      .to(this.currentSlide, 0.7, {
        x: AnimateForward ? '-100%' : '100%',
        ease: Quad.easeInOut
      })
      .to(this.nextSlide, 0.7, {
        x: '0%',
        ease: Quad.easeInOut,
        onComplete: () => {
          this.isAnimating = false;
          this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {
            currentSlide: {
              imageURL: { $set: prevState.nextSlide.imageURL },
              index: { $set: prevState.nextSlide.index },
              subtitle: { $set: prevState.nextSlide.subtitle },
              textColor: { $set: prevState.nextSlide.textColor },
              title: { $set: prevState.nextSlide.title }
            },
            nextSlide: {
              imageURL: { $set: '' },
              index: { $set: 0 },
              subtitle: { $set: '' },
              textColor: { $set: '' },
              title: { $set: '' }
            },
            nextSlideIsLoaded: { $set: false }
          }));
        }
      }, '-=0.7');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <LooksBrowserWrapper>
        <CurrentSlideWrapper innerRef={div => this.currentSlide = div} >
          <SlideImage src={this.state.currentSlide.imageURL} alt={this.state.currentSlide.title} />
          <SlideText>
            <SlideTitle color={this.state.currentSlide.textColor}>{this.state.currentSlide.title}</SlideTitle>
            <SlideSubtitle color={this.state.currentSlide.textColor}>{this.state.currentSlide.subtitle}</SlideSubtitle>
          </SlideText>
        </CurrentSlideWrapper>
        {this.state.nextSlide.imageURL &&
          <NextSlideWrapper innerRef={div => this.nextSlide = div}>
            <SlideImage src={this.state.nextSlide.imageURL} alt={this.state.nextSlide.title} onLoad={this.nextSlideIsLoaded} />
            <SlideText>
              <SlideTitle color={this.state.nextSlide.textColor}>{this.state.nextSlide.title}</SlideTitle>
              <SlideSubtitle color={this.state.nextSlide.textColor}>{this.state.nextSlide.subtitle}</SlideSubtitle>
            </SlideText>
          </NextSlideWrapper>
        }
      </LooksBrowserWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Then now my tests for my `LooksBrowser` component (following is the full code):

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'jest-styled-components';
import LooksBrowser from './../src/app/components/LooksBrowser/LooksBrowser';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Compare snapshots', () => {
  const Component = renderer.create(<LooksBrowser currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />);

  const Tree = Component.toJSON();
  expect(Tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('Renders without crashing', () => {
  mount(<LooksBrowser currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />);
});

test('Check if componentDidUpdate gets called', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(LooksBrowser.prototype, 'componentDidUpdate');
  const Component = mount(<LooksBrowser currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />);

  Component.setProps({ nextSlide: { imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D2_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 2, subtitle: 'Don\'t walk here at night', title: 'What A View', textColor: '#fff' } });
  expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});

test('Check if animateToNextSlide gets called', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(LooksBrowser.prototype, 'animateToNextSlide');
  const Component = mount(<LooksBrowser currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />);

  Component.setProps({ nextSlide: { imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D2_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 2, subtitle: 'Don\'t walk here at night', title: 'What A View', textColor: '#fff' } });
  Component.setState({ nextSlideIsLoaded: true });
  expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

Before I implemented theming all of these tests were passing. After I implemented theming I get the following error from every test:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'SlideTitle' of undefined

  44 |   line-height: 1;
  45 |   color: ${props => props.color};
> 46 |   font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily};
  47 |   font-size: ${PXToVW(52)};
  48 | `;
  49 |
```

Ok, makes sense. The theme is not defined.

## Solution One

So after some googling I found the following 'solution':

https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components#theming

> The recommended solution is to pass the theme as a prop:
>   `const wrapper = shallow(<Button theme={theme} />)`

So I add the following code to my `LooksBrowser` test file:

```
const theme = {
  LooksBrowser: {
    SlideTitle: {
      FontFamily: 'Futura-Light, sans-serif'
    },
    SlideSubtitle: {
      FontFamily: 'Futura-Demi, sans-serif'
    }
  }
};
```

And edit all my tests to pass the theme manually. For example:

```
test('Compare snapshots', () => {
  const Component = renderer.create(<LooksBrowser theme={theme} currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />);

  const Tree = Component.toJSON();
  expect(Tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

After I've done this I run my tests again. Still the same error occurs.

## Solution Two

I decided to wrap my components inside of the Styled Components [ThemeProvider](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming). This fixes the errors from my `Compare snapshots` and `Renders without crashing` tests.

However, since I'm also changing the props/state of my `LooksBrowser` component and testing the results, this doesn't work anymore. This is because the `setProps` and `setState` functions only can be used on the root/wrapper component.

So wrapping my components in the `ThemeProvider` component isn't a valid solution either.

## Solution Three

I decided to try the log the props of one of my Styled Components. So I changed my `SlideTitle` subcomponent to this:

```
const SlideTitle = styled.p`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  color: ${props => {
    console.log(props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily);
    return props.color;
  }};
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily};
  font-size: ${PXToVW(52)};
`;
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'SlideTitle' of undefined

  44 |   line-height: 1;
  45 |   color: ${props => {
> 46 |     console.log(props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily);
  47 |     return props.color;
  48 |   }};
  49 |   font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily};
```

Ok, seems like the entire theme prop is just empty. Let's try manually passing the theme to the `SlideTitle` (which is a horrendous solution btw, it would mean I need to pass my theme manually to every Styled Component in my entire project).

So I added the following code:

```
<SlideTitle theme={this.props.theme} color{this.state.currentSlide.textColor}>{this.state.currentSlide.title}</SlideTitle>
```

And I run my tests again. I see the following line in my terminal:

```
console.log src/app/components/LooksBrowser/LooksBrowser.js:46
Futura-Light, sans-serif
```

Yeah, this is what I'm looking for! I scroll down and see the same error again... *yikes*.

## Solution Four

In the [Jest Styled Components documentation](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components#theming) I also saw the following solution:

```
const shallowWithTheme = (tree, theme) => {
  const context = shallow(<ThemeProvider theme={theme} />)
    .instance()
    .getChildContext()
  return shallow(tree, { context })
}

const wrapper = shallowWithTheme(<Button />, theme)
```

Ok, looks promising. So I added this function to my test file and updated my `Check if componentDidUpdate gets called` test to this:

```
test('Check if componentDidUpdate gets called', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(LooksBrowser.prototype, 'componentDidUpdate');
  const Component = shallowWithTheme(<LooksBrowser currentSlide={{ imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D1_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 1, subtitle: 'Where amazing happens', title: 'The United States of America', textColor: '#fff' }} nextSlide={{ imageURL: '', index: 0, subtitle: '', title: '', textColor: '' }} />, Theme);

  Component.setProps({ nextSlide: { imageURL: 'http://localhost:3001/img/D2_VW_SPW.jpg', index: 2, subtitle: 'Don\'t walk here at night', title: 'What A View', textColor: '#fff' } });
  expect(spy).toBeCalled();
});
```

I run the test and get the following error:

```
Error
Cannot tween a null target. thrown
```

Makes sense since I'm using [shallow](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html). So I change the function to use [mount](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) instead of shallow:

```
const shallowWithTheme = (tree, theme) => {
  const context = mount(<ThemeProvider theme={theme} />)
    .instance()
    .getChildContext()
  return mount(tree, { context })
}
```

I run my test again and voila:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'SlideTitle' of undefined`

I'm officially out of ideas.

If anyone has any thoughts on this it would be *greatly* appreciated! Thanks in advance everyone.

### EDIT

I've now also opened two issues on Github, one in the [Styled Components repo](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1471) and one in the [Jest Styled Components repo](https://github.com/styled-components/jest-styled-components/issues/119).

I've tried all of the solutions provided there so far without any avail. So if anyone here has **any ideas** on how to fix this problem please share them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to fix this problem with help of a colleague. I had another component extend the `SlideTitle` component which broke the test:

```
const SlideSubtitle = SlideTitle.extend`
  font-family: ${props => 
  props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideSubtitle.FontFamily};
`;
```

I refactored my code to this:

```
const SlideTitlesSharedStyling = styled.p`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  color: ${props => props.color};
  font-size: ${PXToVW(52)};
`;

const SlideTitle = SlideTitlesSharedStyling.extend`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideTitle.FontFamily};
`;

const SlideSubtitle = SlideTitlesSharedStyling.extend`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.LooksBrowser.SlideSubtitle.FontFamily};
`;
```

And my tests starting passing again!

Answer (score 13):

Wrapping the `ThemeProvider` around the component and passing the `theme` object to it, works fine for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

import Home from '../Home';
import { themelight } from '../../Layout/theme';

afterEach(cleanup);

test('home renders correctly', () => {
  let { getByText } = render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={themelight}>
      <Home name={name} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );

  getByText('ANURAG HAZRA');
})
```

Comment: This worked from me! Only difference is that I have a more complex ThemeProvider setup (https://gist.github.com/eyerean/84210966cc8822d88260c3c08c891981), but I can still wrap the components in my tests with it and the tests pass.