# How to use styled-components theme with react-native testing-library

Tags: react-native, styled-components, react-native-testing-library

I've got a simple component:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { ViewStyle, StyleProp, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import {
    RoundedCardBackground,
} from './index';

type RoundedCardProps = {
    style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
    shadow?: boolean;
};

const RoundedCard: FunctionComponent<RoundedCardProps> = ({
    style,
    children,
    shadow,
}) => {
    let shadowStyle = shadow ? styles.shadow : undefined;
    return (
        <RoundedCardBackground style={[shadowStyle]}>
            {children}
        </RoundedCardBackground>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
        elevation: 2,
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 3,
        },
        shadowRadius: 10,
        shadowOpacity: 0.05,
    },
});

export default RoundedCard;
```

and I'm trying to test out a simple functionality but I'm getting an error that's coming from styled-components theme.

Here's my test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from '/components/atoms';
import { render } from '/utilities/testUtils';
import theme from '../../themes/primary';

import RoundedCard from './RoundedCard';

describe('RoundedCard', () => {
    it('displays correct children', () => {
        const { queryByText } = render(
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <RoundedCard>
                    <Text>Test</Text>
                </RoundedCard>,
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
        expect(queryByText('Test')).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'white' of undefined

      79 | export const RoundedCardBackground = styled.View`
      80 |     flex-shrink: 1;
    > 81 |     background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
         |                                                       ^
      82 |     border-radius: 6px;
      83 |     overflow: hidden;
      84 | `;
```

Is there something that I'm missing? I thought that wrapping the component in ThemeProvider would do the trick, but still getting the error.

Just for reference, this is the styled-component that's throwing the error

```js
export const RoundedCardBackground = styled.View`
    flex-shrink: 1;
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.white};
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the issue I was having was changing

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
```

to

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components/native';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Jest (or other test utility) cant find `props.theme` because theme is `undefined`. You have to pass theme to your component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from '/components/atoms';
import { render } from '/utilities/testUtils';

import RoundedCard from './RoundedCard';

const theme = {
    colors: {
        white: "#fff"
    }
}

describe('RoundedCard', () => {
    it('displays correct children', () => {
        const { queryByText } = render(
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <RoundedCard>
                    <Text>Test</Text>
                </RoundedCard>,
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
        expect(queryByText('Test')).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my import for theme. I edited my question and included that. Even with me importing my theme or manually putting in the theme like you just did, I still get the same issue

Comment: Then I think you should change your `render` method. Check this [link](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render)

Comment: I adjusted my utilities/testUtils file to match everything in that link and used that render in the link you posted. It still throws the same error.

Comment: I found [same problem on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503037/cant-get-jest-to-work-with-styled-components-which-contain-theming). I recommend use Jest for your test-components and pass `theme` to your component.